# Atribuir nomes dinamicos

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho um teste na minha base de dados, e a cada pergunta tem as suas respostas (Certa, Errada1, Errada2, Errada3 ). Eu consigo listar as perguntas em formulários diferentes, mas o meu problema é listar as respostas em `radiobuttons` com nomes diferentes. Visto que se todos tiverem o mesmo nome, ao selecionar um, os outros vão ser desconsiderados.

```
    <?php

        $instS='Select * from perguntas';
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$instS);

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query))
         {echo"<br>";
                echo"<center><fieldset style='border:solid; width:500px;'>";

                  echo" <legend style='background: #FF9; width:150px; border: solid 1px black; 
                                -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
                                border-radius: 8px; padding: 6px;'> QuestÃ£o: ".$row['idPergunta']."";echo"</legend>";

             echo "<center> <h4><b> Pergunta: </h4></center></b>";

        echo"<center>"
            .$row['textoPerguntas'].""; //Buscar a pergunta a base de dados
         echo"<center>";

        echo "<center><h4><b> Resposta: </h4></center></b>";

        // queria aqui buscar as respostas, mas de modo a que a cada set de 4    perguntas, os nomes das radiobuttons fossem alterados (RespostaCerta,Errada1,Errada2,Errada3 name=questao1), 
(RespostaCerta,Errada1,Errada2,Errada3 name=questao2), etc, consoante ao numero de perguntas que existe

        echo "<input type='radio' name='dd' id='resposta'>";

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>"; 

                                ?>
```

Comment: Você não consegue usar: pergunta_id_resposta_id?

Comment: o que quer dizer com isso ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, as respostas estão ficando duplicadas, resp_1, resp_2, correto? Exemplo: `<input type='radio' name='perg_1_resp_1' />`

Comment: Sim exato.. E eu queria saber se tem como eu posso atribuir automaticamente " name=pertg1_rest1",   " name=pertg1_rest2", " name=pertg1_rest3", 
"name=pertg2_rest1" e por assim em diante

Comment: visto que eu estou a retirar as respostas e as perguntas da base de dados

Comment: Mas se você colocar eles com o mesmo `name` você poderá marcar mais e um radio button, nao?

Answer (score 0):

> Sim exato.. E eu queria saber se tem como eu posso atribuir automaticamente " name=pertg1_rest1", " name=pertg1_rest2", " name=pertg1_rest3", "name=pertg2_rest1" e por assim em diante

Você está usando `input radio`, se você atribuir names diferentes para as opções não faz sentindo utilizar `input radio`, porque elas poderão ser marcadas mais de uma ao mesmo tempo

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='dd' id='resposta'>";
```

Neste exemplo você não esta pegando a opção de nenhum lugar, então você pode simplesmente alterar suas names manualmente:

```
<?php
$instS='Select * from perguntas';
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$instS);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query)):
    $radioname = "pergunta-".$row['idPergunta'];
    $retorna = '<br>'
        ."<center><fieldset style='border:solid; width:500px;'>"
        ."<legend style='background: #FF9; width:150px; border: solid 1px black -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; ; border-radius: 8px; padding: 6px;'"
        ."QuestÃ£o: ".$row['idPergunta']
        ."</legend>"
        ."<center> <h4><b> Pergunta: </h4></center></b><center>".$row['textoPerguntas']."<center>"
        ."<center><h4><b> Resposta: </h4></center></b>"
        ."<input type='radio' name='".$radioname."-1' id='resposta-1'> Opção 1"
        ."<input type='radio' name='".$radioname."-2' id='resposta-2'> Opção 2"
        ."<input type='radio' name='".$radioname."-3' id='resposta-3'> Opção 3"
        ."<input type='radio' name='".$radioname."-4' id='resposta-4'> Opção 4"
        ."<br/><br/>";
    echo $retorna;
endwhile;
```

Comment: Não funciona :/
eu tenho na mesma tabela as respostas erradas. que são RespostaErrada1, RespostaErrada2, RespostaErrada3.. E mesmo assim não consigo criar um grupo para que apenas se possa selecionar as respostas dessa questão..